# Button working everywhere but default.aspx

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, web-controls

I have an ASP.NET page which has a usercontrol to log in a user. The control appears on every page, and works everywhere except default.aspx. When I click it on default.aspx, the page posts back to the same page and get a 404. Failed request tracing doesn't seem to reveal anything. The code for the button is:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Sign In" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

I can't see any reason this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be redirecting to default.aspx on login. It works everywhere else because you are redirecting to the default but breaks when you are on default.aspx itself.

Check the login redirect function in debug mode and see what exactly is happening.

Comment: The handler for the button isn't even called though, so no redirect gets issues (there isn't one anyway).

Comment: Then there is something on the default.aspx thats breaking before it hits the login click event handler. If possible, try removing everything else , check the user control, and then add other stuff back one at time.

Answer (score 0):

Look for multiple forms in the rendered source, and make sure your button occurs within the form. This can cause lots of problems with postback.

To be more clear. No nested forms. Asp:buttons or anything that uses postback MUST be inside the page's *singular unnested* form.